# Is freemarker template HTML escaped by default

Tags: html, templates, freemarker, templating

I just started working with freemarker templates. I want to make sure that they are HTML escaped to avoid XSS vulnerabilities.

I tried using this template and passed anchor tag as a variable

```
String dummyAnchorTagVariable = "<a href='https://example.com'>Visit mysite</a>"
```

and used it in freemarker template

```
<div> ${dummyAnchorTagVariable} </div>
```

Result of this was seeing whole text including tags on the webpage and not as a link. So I assume that freemarker is **HTML escaped by default**

But when I try to find the documentation related to it, I don't find it anywhere that says Freemarker is HTML escaped by default 
http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_escape.html

and there is even a blog post (although old) that describes how make it escape by default) http://watchitlater.com/blog/2011/10/default-html-escape-using-freemarker/

So I'm kind of confused about the HTML escaping in Freemarker.

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker before 2.3.24 is not escaped by default, unless someone is using a custom `TemplateLoader` that puts the template inside `<#escape x as x?html>...</#escape>`. If that's what happening in your case, then `<#noescape>${dummyAnchorTagVariable}</#noescape>` will work, otherwise it will give an error because there's no active `#escape` to disable.

FreeMarker 2.3.24 can auto-escape without `TemplateLoader` tricks (as of this writing it's not yet out, but hopefully RC1 comes in days and final in February).